# Accessing Cam Web Interface over a VPN

Tags: webcam, vpn, pi-1

I have 2 Raspbery Pi's (B+) set up in 2 different locations:

- **RPi 1** is at home. It is connected to the internet and port forwarding is allowed. I am able to SSH into it from another location. I have also set up [PiVPN](http://www.pivpn.io/) on this RPi.
- **RPi 2** is at a room in the city where I study. It is connected to the internet but port forwarding is not allowed. I am able to connect it to the *VPN-Pi* at home and thus SSH into it over the internet (first SSH into RPi 1, then SSH into RPi 2).

A **camera** is attached to the **RPi 2**. I want to be able to access that camera over the internet. More specifically, I am trying to view the [RPi Cam Web Interface](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) in a browser. Since port forwarding is not allowed, I'm trying to figure this out out with help of the VPN.

Right now, I can SSH into **RPi 2** over the internet, but I just don't know how to get to the Cam Web Interface.

Any help or steering into the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why I have overseen this, but I've "discovered" the answer myself.

The solution is to connect to the *VPN-RPi* with the device you are trying to view the interface with, using the OpenVPN Windows client. Then, SSH into RPi 1 and find out the "local" IP address of the second RPi using `pivpnv -c`. Using this IP address, you can access the interface in your browser, just like you would do locally.

If there's another solution (e.g. not having to connect to the VPN), I would love to hear about it!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

You can **either** set up a forwarded Port directly to the webcam's gui (Port 80 for example)

**OR** you can use a VPN connection, which turns your Pi accessible to other networks (no port forwarding needed!).

I have no idea why someone would need both, but it sounds like you're missing some routing information on the VPN connection.

Comment: Yes, the second solution works fine and is secure. Setting up a forwarded port doesn't seem possible. My ISP only allows port forwarding for devices on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet and allows only matching ports (internal port cannot be different from external port). The devices on the VPN are on the 10.8.0.0/24 subnet.